# Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine, unity-container

#FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.#

```
Where:
Build file '/Users/amboji/Documents/react-native-unity-main/example/unity/builds/android/unityLibrary/build.gradle' line: 66
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask'.

> NDK is not installed

Using this library - [@azesmway/react-native-unity](https://github.com/azesmway/react-native-unity)

Comment: Unity requires NDK to build IL2CPP back end project. Make sure you installed correct NDK version

Comment: @Jaimin I installed correct NDK version

Comment: Can you check if the ndk is installed properly on your Android studio? Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SKD Tools Tab > Make sure "NDK" is selected.

Answer (score 4):

**This worked for me!!**

Add ndkVersion same as in the android studio [project_root]/unity/builds/android/unityLibrary/build.gradle

```
android { 
... 
ndkVersion = "21.3.6528147" 
... 
}
```